# Mysql: Compare and filter time entries

Tags: mysql, filter, compare

I have an table with user ids and login dates.

```
id | customer | timestamp  
1  | 1        | 2017-02-10 11:30:28  
2  | 1        | 2017-02-11 11:30:28  
3  | 2        | 2017-02-12 11:30:28  
4  | 3        | 2017-02-13 11:30:28  
5  | 1        | 2017-02-14 11:30:28
```

**Now I want to get the count of the longest continuous streak of logins per customer.**

I got to the point, where the difference is calculated correctly for one customer.

```
SELECT  a.id aId,
    b.id bId,
    a.customer,
    a.timestamp aTime,
    b.timestamp bTime,
    DATEDIFF(b.timestamp, a.timestamp) as diff
FROM logins a
INNER JOIN logins b
    ON a.customer = b.customer AND a.id < b.id
WHERE b.customer = 7
GROUP BY a.id
```

How can I do this for the whole table and count the following logins with a difference under 1 day?

The wanted result for this example should be:

```
customer | days of continuous login  
1        | 2  
2        | 1  
3        | 1
```

Comment: What should be the output in your example?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a LEFT JOIN

**Query**

```
SELECT 
   logins.customer
 , COUNT(*) as "longest continuous streak of logins"
FROM ( 

SELECT 
  login1.*
FROM 
 login login1 
LEFT JOIN 
 login login2
ON
 login1.timestamp < login2.timestamp
AND
 # Only JOIN if date diff is less or equal then 1 day
 DATEDIFF(login2.timestamp, login1.timestamp) <= 1 
WHERE
   login2.id IS NOT NULL
 AND
   login2.customer IS NOT NULL
 AND
   login2.timestamp IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 
 login1.customer

) 
 AS logins
GROUP BY
 logins.customer
```

**Result**

```
| customer | longest continuous streak of logins |
|----------|-------------------------------------|
|        1 |                                   2 |
|        2 |                                   1 |
|        3 |                                   1 |
```

see demo http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad581/17

Comment: Thank you for the answer, unfortunately it didn't give the expected result. The lesser problem, I could solve by my own, was the check for the identical customer.id in the LEFT JOIN. The harder one is the streak. Your solution lists all logins which are lower than 1 day difference. But I need to break this streak, if a longer pause is between the logins.